# mod_rewrite for PHP RESTful Server

Tags: apache, rest, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm developing a PHP RESTful server for an API locally on my mac.

I've managed to enable mod_rewrite and have Overrides allowed for the site directory (~/Sites/api).

In ~/Sites/api is the .htaccess file and index.php. I'd like to rewrite all requests to http://localhost/~myusername/api/* to index.php. I need to preserve the query parameters, but that's it.

I've tried the following in the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

This gives a 500:Internal Server Error.

Commenting out the `FollowSymLinks` line gives a 403:Forbidden error.

I can access index.php fine without the rewrites in place.

Any help you could offer would be much appreciated. I feel like weeping at the moment.

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 7):

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ index.php?handler=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Where the handler is what is passed to your index.php script.  For instance, a request for

> http://localhost/~myusername/api/getUser/myusername

would be rewritten to

> http://localhost/~myusername/api/index.php?handler=getUser/myusername

Comment: You should exclude `index.php`.

Comment: @Gumbo: please provide explanation with your statement if you don't mind.:)

Comment: @kaziTanvirAhsan That comment is more than three years old. I have no idea what it was supposed to mean.

Comment: @kaziTanvirAhsan Ok, now I know what it supposed to mean: `^api/(.*)$` will also match `api/index.php`. Therefore `index.php` should be excluded to be matched by this rule, e. g., with an additional `RewriteCond $1 !=index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `[L]` means stop rewriting *this* URL, but you're generating a new URL with `index.php`, which will be rewritten as well, causing infinite loop.

Add `RewriteCond` that excludes `index.php` from being rewritten.